# $a\overset{\vert}{\smile}_{A}b$ iff $MR(a/A)=MR(a/Ab)$ in totally transcendental theories

Tags: model-theory

Let $T$ be totally transcendental theory. (stable in particular)

I want to prove that $a\overset{\vert}{\smile}_{A}b$ iff $MR(a/A)=MR(a/Ab)$

Well we know that since $T$ is totally transcendental then every formula and in prticular every type has a Morely Rank. So we can talk about the problem.

And $T$ is stable so forking and dividing coincide.

By that i managed to prove the "$\Leftarrow$" direction, by showing that if $tp(a/Ab)$ forks over $A$ then $MR(a/A)>MR(a/Ab)$.

But i can't manage to prove the second direction. I though maybe to assume that $MR(a/A)>MR(a/Ab)$ and take $\varphi \in tp(a/A)$ and $\psi \in tp(a/Ab)$ s.t $\psi(\mathfrak C)\subseteq\varphi(\mathfrak C)$ ($\mathfrak C$ is the monster) with $MR\psi<MR\varphi$. Than to find some how a way to show that $\psi$ divides.

Comment: This question was asked again recently, but in a slightly more general form (without assuming totally transcendental - well, maybe that was accidental on the part of the asker). Anyway, I answered the more recent question before I realized it had been asked before. I've closed this question as a duplicate, so that someone who stumbles across it can find the answer at the linked question.